# Pod install on the other branch not main

Tags: ios, swift, github, cocoapods

I got a project from github and created a new branch on my machine, now I am thinking about installing pods. So if I install pods on my branch, will it be installed on main branch?

Comment: No. A git manage files, and a pod only add/modify files, so until you merge back to the main branch, pod will only be on the branch you're in.

Comment: Cool! Thnx) @Larme